Proof of cardinality of cartesian product
There's a part of the proof for $|M \times N| = |M| \ \times |N|$ that I'm currently stuck on. The function defined between the two is
$$
h \ \colon \ \{1,...,m\} \ \times \ \{1,...n\} \to \{1,...,mn\}, \text{where} \\
h(a,b) = m(b-1) + a
$$
I've already proven it is injective, but surjection feels more difficult. To prove surjection I let $y \in \{1,...,mn\}$. I don't know how to get specific $a$, $b$, for $h(a,b) = y$. How would one construct an expression for $y$ to get the desired result?

Does this answer your question? Bijection proof. (especially the short answer) See also here.

Have you tried some examples? Say $m=3$, $n=5$?
